# Laravel 5.4 access denied for user root@localhost on migrate

Tags: laravel, mariadb, credentials

I have a stange one with Laravel. I have a bad habit of creating projects on virtual box with laravel project for testing. (debian last stable currently 9.1, nginx, php7.1, MariaDB).

Before you tell me to go read another post somewhere, please read everything, I mays have missed the post but I tried quite à lot I tried most of the solution that may have worked for others, but they don't in my case (thanks).

I tried different thing and always end breaking everything and doing hover (that's normal...).

I have already tried a number of installation and never had any problem with

```
php artisan migrate
```

That is until today. I prepared my migrations files and tried the migrate and I got this message :

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: sele
  ct * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = test and table_nam
  e = migrations)
```

And this one:

```
[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I did everything as always, I checked my credentials that are in the .env file and tested them. No problem there.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=Password2
```

The database does exist, can't be wrong with this name :

```
SHOW DATABASEs;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

When looking for code error 1698 in MariaDB, they tell me that this code appear when it's trying to connect without password.

So my question is why is it doing this? I tried with a new project, just installed and doing the artisan command line, it changes nothing.

I would like to avoid doing a fresh os install.

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Did you accidentally forget to ssh into the virtualbox first?

Comment: did u run the command within the virtualbox?

Comment: Yeah... I'm on windows and virtualbox, can't really make a mistake as I'm using putty to connect :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved my problem... It seems that I need to create a new database account to write in the database and can't use root...

I tested it with another virtual machine and if I create a new account it works as it should...

Seems that the issue is with MariaDB... I can connect with or without password to root even after mysql_secure_installation command... I will work on this...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14):

For me 'root' user could not connect. Here's how to solve it:

1.login to mysql console `$ mysql -u root -p`

2.create new user

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

3.grant privilages to your laravel database

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

or grant privilages to all tables

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

4.flush privilages for changes to take place

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

5.exit mysql console

```
exit
```

6.edit `.env` file, update your `MASTER_DB_USER` and `MASTER_DB_PASS` to match your new user

7.run migration to test things out

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: That solved my problem as well. `root` user is not working for me but another user works thanks!

Comment: On Debian 11 (Testing), I had to run mysql with root privileges. So simply `sudo mysql -u root -p`

Comment: You are absolutely genius! This work for me in order to GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my laravel database for my user! Many Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Please once you can clear the cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: Hi I had tried those but I tried again, after a good night of sleep we can have surprises... But nope, none of the commands did the trick... Same error.

Answer (score 2):

Have you updated the password from when you first tried to run php artisan ?

Could be as easy as clearing the config cache

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run the following artisan command:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

How [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04#step-2-%E2%80%94-installing-mysql) explains, the authentication is made using ***auth_socket***, so you have to change it to ***mysql_native_password***

Run this sql into mysql with root user:

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me. I did the following steps to change the root user's password.

- Goto Sudo mode with `sudo su` and open mysql with either `mysql` or `msyql -u root` (no password required for database)
- Now use this command to change password `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<your-new-password>';`
- Done