# Migration execution error after creating Laravel table

Tags: php, laravel

**.env**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:21LS3qiIStEjMUez8/y9hrr6mQXp+5U7Y/Omr8ve3wk=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=1234

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

**2023_06_09_044521_create_admin_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('admin', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admin');
    }
};
```

I ran the php artisan migrate command, but an Illuminate\Database\QueryException error occurred, so I ran it after entering the php artisan config:clear command, but the error was not resolved.

[image]

I'm not sure what's causing the error. Please tell me how to solve it.

After creating the file through Laravel migration, I modified the column and ran the php artisan migrate command, but in the .env environment setting, it says that the mysql connection information is not working well, but the error cannot be resolved. help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.4 access denied for user root@localhost on migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471494/laravel-5-4-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-on-migrate)

Comment: You are having wrong DB details. Verify it in your `.env` file

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: do `php artisan optimize`  to clear all things since the error says "using password:no" and in your `.env` you are using a password for DB.

Answer (score 0):

Your database credentials are wrong, verify your .env has the right values (you can try getting in the database with a database viewer tool, when that works update your env with the right values)